# Why different web browsers interpret web page different

Tags: browser, webbrowser-control, compatibility

Why every web browser interpret the web page different. Is it some standard for interpreting HTML, CSS or JavaScript or that depends of company witch development the web browser.

Comment: No comment downvote isn't very community spirited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser is what interprets the html. The browser engineers do have a standard to go by, but in the end, they choose how their browser will interpret and display the html, css, etc, and how it will function.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard specification set by the [World Wide Web Consortium](http://w3.org/).  Most browsers follow it pretty well.  Firefox, Opera, et. al. follow it pretty much to the letter but Internet Explorer does not in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

actually yes it depends upon the interpretation of CSS and in turn, many tags.
This [article](http://www.search-this.com/2007/03/12/no-margin-for-error/) provides some more insight on the matter.